# Javascript validation for radio button are not working

Tags: javascript, html

Suppose i have this piece of my html code

```
<!--Marital Status-->
            <div class="gap">
                <table>
                    <tr class="parent">
                        <td>Martial Status:</td>
                        <td>&emsp;
                            <input type="radio" id="rad1" name="Status" value="1">
                            <label for="Single">Single</label>
                            <br>&emsp;
                            <input type="radio" id="rad2" name="Status" value="2">
                            <label for="Married">Married</label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
```

and for the javascript

```
function validateForm() {
var status = document.getElementsByName("Status");
var validradio = false;
var i = 0;
  while(!validradio && i < status.length){
    if(status[i].checked) validradio = true;
    }
    i++;

  if (!validradio){
    alert("Please select your marital status");
    return false;
  }
}
```

when i try the validation without checking the radio button, the page become not responsive and the alert box didn't pop up as it should. But when i checked one of the checkbox, the page turn out just find. May i know, what's going on?

Comment: Not related to your poblem but keep the `table` tag for tabular data. If you're using it for layout, you're using it wrong.

Comment: _not responding browser_ usually means infinite loop. In your case you close your `while` loop directly after `if(status[i].checked)`, so your `i` never increments -> infinite loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've misaligned one statement in the javascript, change it to:

```
function validateForm() {
    var status = document.getElementsByName("Status");
    var validradio = false;
    var i = 0;
    while(!validradio && i < status.length){
        if(status[i].checked) validradio = true;
        i++;
    }
    if (!validradio){
        alert("Please select your marital status");
        return false;
    }
}
```

With `i++` outside of the loop, `i` forever remained at value `0`.

Answer (score 0):

This can be simplified immensly. Use `querySelectorAll` with an attribute selector and the `:checked` pseudo class and count the result

```js
function validateForm() {
  
  //Use an attribute selector with :checked to get the number of selected  
  if (document.querySelectorAll("[name=Status]:checked").length < 1;) {
    alert("Please select your marital status");
    return false;
  }
}

document.getElementById("validate").addEventListener("click", validateForm);
```

```html
<div class="gap">
  <table>
    <tr class="parent">
      <td>Martial Status:</td>
      <td>&emsp;
        <input type="radio" id="rad1" name="Status" value="1">
        <label for="Single">Single</label>
        <br>&emsp;
        <input type="radio" id="rad2" name="Status" value="2">
        <label for="Married">Married</label>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<button id="validate">Validate</button>
```